# Не могу установить Pyinstaller . Подскажите как исправить ошибку. Пожалуйста буду очень благодарен

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\мой\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\мой\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\9869~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnhkd9ges'
         cwd: C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0lku77bc\PyInstaller
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Мой\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-tnpqvt86\PyInstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\мой\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\мой\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\9869~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpnhkd9ges' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Ещё возможно не устанавливается из - за кирилицы в пути

Comment: C:\Users\Мой\ если планируете изучать python смените имя компьютера на латиницу

Answer (score 0):

*Попробуйте установить последнюю версию*

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller не работает в python 3.8. Разработчики на своем github делают сборы на дальнейшую разработку. Скачайте версию 3.7 и все будет работать.

Comment: У меня была такая же проблема, и когда я начал смотреть в ее корни узнал о сборах, в которых вы можете поучаствовать для дальнейшего использования данной утилиты. Если вам это интересно покапайтесь в репозитории Pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

Как было сказано ниже, есть возможные проблемы с установкой на более новых версиях Python. Соответственно, если у вас даже после установки весит новая версия, попробуйте сделать это:

Узнаём расположение нашего Python (в пуске ищем папку Python, кликаем ПКМ по ней, нажимаем на пункт "Расположение файла", дальше, если видим ярлыки вместо папок и файлов питона, нажимаем ПКМ по ярлыку, и жмём "Расположение файла", так мы оказались в директории питона), переходим в папку Scripts, копируем путь к ней. Далее с помощью поиска, пишем ключевые слова: переменных сред, нажимаем на Изменение системных переменных среды. Нажимаем на кнопку "Переменные среды...". Выбираем переменную "PATH" и нажимаем "Изменить". Нажимаем на кнопку "Создать" и вставляем путь к папке Scripts, скопированный нами ранее. Сохраняем это всё, выходим из окон. Перезапускаем cmd, вуаля!